# "Is there a best X?" — why "a" if it's the superlative degree?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, superlative-degree

Which of the following is grammatical?

> 1. Is there a best school?
> 2. Is there the best school?

I'm sure that the first one is right. But why?

Comment: I take it your primary language doesn’t have articles. Is that right?

Comment: @tchrist not every language that does have articles would use the indefinite one there. Just because English has feature X, doesn't mean it uses it in The One Right Way.

Answer (score 1):

*The* is the definite article. *A* is the indefinite article.

The question "Is there a best school?' is, by its nature, indefinite. Ergo, *a*.

EXPANDED ANSWER:

It is necessary to determine the meaning of the question. Does it mean

> 1. Does there exist a school that we would consider to be "the best"?
>      *or*
> 2. Is the best school (which I know exists) in the particular location to which I am pointing?

Without more context, most native English speakers would interpret the question as in number 1.  In that case, the declarative form of the sentences would be

> There is a best school.

This is an adverbial use of *there* [meaning](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/there)

> (3.) (usually **there is/are**) used to indicate the fact or existence of something: ***there*** comes a point where you give up

The sentence means that a best thing exists, but we are not indicating which particular school is best. The reference is indefinite as to which school merits the title, so the indefinite article ***a*** is used.

If the intended meaning is that described in number 2, the declarative sentence would be

> There [pointing] is the best school.

In that case, *there* is used as an adverb [meaning](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/there)

> (1.) in, at, or to that place or position: *we went on to Paris and stayed **there** eleven days*

If that was what was intended, a particular school is being identified, and the definite article ***the*** would be used. However, most English speakers would not use this construction.

Comment: Although in a conversation I could imagine someone saying, "Is *there* the best school?" while pointing at a map.

Comment: Yes, but in that context, the indefiniteness is about the location, not the identification of the institution. Further, "Is *that* the best school?" is definite that there is *a* best school, and the indefiniteness is about the identification. A subtle parsing.

Comment: Ok thanks bib. But there is a problem with my teacher he is saying that if we create a question with the superlative we shouldn't change the article. I need an strong argumentation. He just don't get it.

Comment: @user36662 See expanded answer.